# what a method 'books=(books)' is doing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, virtus

I joined Rails team and maintain the codes.
Some of the objects are controlled by Gem virtus, but I really don't understand like below code is doing.

I understand the result that the attribute 'latest_book' can collect latest book from Books but why it can be done? What 'books=(books)' is doing? and Why 'super books' is here?

```
class GetBooks
  include Virtus.model
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attribute :books, Array[Book]
  attribute :latest_book, Book

  def books=(books)
    self.latest_book = books.sort_by { |book| book['createdate'] }.last
    super books
  end
end
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`def books=(books)` is defining a method called `books=` which takes a single argument `books`. Yes, that's confusing. It should probably be `def books=(value)` or `def books=(new_books)`.

And yes, the `=` is part of the method name. `self.books = value` is really syntax sugar for `self.books=(value)`. Again, the method is `books=`.

`super books` is `super(books)`. `super` calls the next inherited or included method of the same name; it's calling `books=` created by `attribute :books, Array[Book]`. This is a ["method override"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding) which allows you to add to the behavior of an existing method.

When `books=` is called it updates `latest_books` and then calls its the original method to set the `books` attribute.

```
gb = GetBooks.new
gb.books = [old_book, new_book]

p gb.latest_book # new_book
p gb.books       # [old_book, new_book]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! What I wanted to know was this point.
"created by attribute :books, Array[Book]."
and then understand "method override", in this case, setter override is used.

Comment: @d.y you could also use `super` instead of `super books` since it passes the arguments along by default.